# Accessing HDFS on Cloudera with Java and Kerberos Keytab from Windows

Tags: java, hdfs, kerberos, cloudera, keytab

I'm trying to connect to my HDFS instance running on Cloudera. My first step was enabling Kerberos and creating Keytabs (as shown [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_sg_kadmin_kerberos_keytab.html)).

In the next step i would like to authenticate with a keytab.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://cloudera:8020");
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hdfs@CLOUDERA", "/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab");

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
FileStatus[] fsStatus = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"));
for (int i = 0; i < fsStatus.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(fsStatus[i].getPath().toString());
}
```

It fails with the following error

> java.io.IOException: Login failure for hdfs@CLOUDERA from keytab
>   /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab:
>   javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password
>   from user

The question is: how do I correctly handle the keytab? Do i have to copy it to my local machine?

Comment: The keytab file **must** be readable from your client program. It contains your password (in a hashed format) that will be sent (encrypted) to the KDC service so that you can authenticate, and get a Kerberos ticket as proof of your identity. Note that you'd better restrict access to the keytab, otherwise anyone could "steal" the file then authenticate as you from anywhere!!!

Comment: To enable the Kerberos debug trace,`export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` plus `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html

Comment: Note that if your client runs on Windows, then you will need to download a Windows version of the Hadoop run-time, because the bloody UGI requires the "native libs" even on the client side *(for no good reason, just because of the non-regression test suite!)*

Comment: Thanks for your replies @SamsonScharfrichter! My client (in this case) is eclipse and i'm working on Windows. I created an HDFS principal and the corresponding keytab on cloudera. Do I have to install a Kerberos Client on Windows?  Do i have to compile the runtime myself (like shown [here](https://dzone.com/articles/build-and-install-hadoop-on-windows-with-native-bi)) or are there any pre-compiled binaries available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running a Hadoop client on Windows to reach a kerberized cluster, you **need** a specific *"native library"* (i.e. DLL).
As far as I can tell there is no good reason for that, because that lib is not actually used outside of some automated regression tests (!?!) so it's a pain inflicted to Hadoop users by Hadoop committers.

To add extra pain, there is no official build of that DLL (and of the Windows "stub" that enable its use from Java). You must either *(a)* build it yourself from source code -- good luck -- or *(b)* search the internet for a downloadable Hadoop-for-Windows runtime, and pray that is does not contain any malware.
The best option (for 64-bit Windows) is here: https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils
...and the ReadMe explains why you can reasonably trust that run-time. But if you are stuck with an older 32-bit Windows, then you are on your own.

Now let's assume you deployed that run-time on your Windows box under
  `C:\Some Dir\hadoop\bin\`
*(the final `bin` is required; the embedded space is just extra fun)*

You must point the Hadoop client to that run-time with a couple of Java properties:
  `"-Dhadoop.home.dir=C:/Some Dir/hadoop" "-Djava.library.path=C:/Some Dir/hadoop/bin"`
*(note the double quotes around Windows args as a whole, to protect embedded spaces in the paths, which have been translated to Java style for extra fun)*
*(in Eclipse, just stuff these props under "VM Arguments", quotes included)*

Now, there's the Kerberos config. If your KDC is your corporate Active Directory server, then Java should find the config parameters automatically. But if your KDC is a standalone "MIT Kerberos" install on Linux, then you have to find a valid `/etc/krb5.conf` file on the cluster, copy it on your Windows box, and have Java use it with an additional property...
  `"-Djava.security.krb5.conf=C:/Some Other Dir/krb5.conf"`

Then let's assume you have created your keytab file on a Linux box, using `ktutil` (or an Active Directory admin created it for you with some AD command) and you dropped the file under
  `C:\Some Other Dir\foo.keytab`
Before anything else, if the keytab is for a real Windows account -- i.e. your own account -- or a Prod service account, then **make sure that keytab is secure!!** Use the Windows Security dialog box to restrict access to your account only *(and maybe System, for backups)*. Because that file could enable anyone, on any machine, to authenticate on the cluster (and any Kerberos-enabled system, including Windows).

Now you can try to authenticate using
`UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("foo@BAR.ORG", "C:/Some Other Dir/foo.keytab");`

If it does not work, enable the Kerberos debug traces with both an environment variable
  `set HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true`
...and a Java property
  `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true`
*(in Eclipse, set these in "Environment" and "VM Arguments" respectively)*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! That's a great advice!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have set proper permissions?

```
 chown hdfs:hadoop /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab
 chmod 440 /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs.keytab
```

Comment: User and rights are set. Do I have to copy the keytab from the server to my local machine? I am not that familiar with Kerberos. At least in my understanding, a keytab is something like a public key!?

Comment: You can copy keytab server in your desktop, you must load with kinit and check with klist