# Access remote kerberized HDFS from windows with java

Tags: windows, hadoop, hdfs, kerberos

I'm trying to work on a Hadoop project , but I'm new to all this concept. I have successfully set up my hadoop cluster on an Ubuntu server to use Kerberos authentication and I can access my HDFS files with the Kerberos ticket. Now I'm trying to write a Java code on my windows machine to access the remote Kerberized HDFS.  This is what I've tried so far:

```
class FileCount
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "PFE.COM");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc","ubuntu:88");

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://192.168.8.101:9000");
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
        conf.set("debug", "true");
        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("hdfs/ubuntu@PFE.COM", 
           "C:/fichiers/hdfs.keytab");

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FileStatus[] fsStatus = fs.listStatus(new Path("/"));
        for(int i = 0; i < fsStatus.length; i++){
          System.out.println(fsStatus[i].getPath().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Login failure for hdfs/ubuntu@PFE.COM from keytab C:/fichiers/hdfs.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: ubuntu
```

I've transfered my keytab file from ubntu server to my windows machine to be able to use it in this code.
Also I don't know if I should have kerberos installed on my windows machine to be able to get this to work. So if you have any idea please help me with it !

Comment: I think you also need to have files like `hdfs-site.xml`, `core-site.xml` etc and `krb5.conf` along with the keytab file, if you try to run this from a Windows machine on which hadoop is not configured.

Comment: `hdfs/ubuntu@PFE.COM` refers to a **service** (i.e. HDFS running on a machine whose DNS canonical name is "ubuntu"). What you need is a **client** login such as `someone@PFE.COM`.

Comment: To debug the Kerberos authentication process, you need a Hadoop-specific flag plus low-level JAAS flags, as explained in https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html >> `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` (or the Windows equivalent)  plus `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` and my personal touch `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext` *(because syntax errors in config files are silently ignored otherwise)*

Comment: The Hadoop client on Windows requires "native libraries" for Kerberos authentication, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855320/accessing-hdfs-on-cloudera-with-java-and-kerberos-keytab-from-windows/42927348

Comment: I had my windows client reading and writing in HDFS  before enabling Kerberos without using hadoop librairies. I think the issue has to do with permissions but I'm not sure what's not working exactly.

Comment: when I run this code from the hadoop machine and not remotely I get this exception :
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to specify server's Kerberos principal name; Host Details : local host is: "ubuntu/192.168.8.101"; destination host is: "ubuntu":9000;