# Use of HiveMetaStoreClient(thereby, HiveConf) to retrieve Hive metadata

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-metastore

Kerberized HDP-2.6.3.0.

I am able to connect to Hive from my Windows machine using the Hive JDBC driver, however, I need to use some methods of the [HiveMetaStoreClient](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r2.1.1/api/index.html). I flipped through the api and wrote a test code which I am executing from an IDE.

```
private static void connectHiveMetastore() throws MetaException, MalformedURLException {
        //System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
        //System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","C:\\kerb5.conf");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        //configuration.addResource("E:\\hdp\\client_config\\HDFS_CLIENT\\core-site.xml");
        //configuration.addResource("E:\\hdp\\client_config\\HDFS_CLIENT\\hdfs-site.xml");
        HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf(configuration,Configuration.class);
        //URL url = new File("E:\\hdp\\client_config\\HDFS_CLIENT\\hive-site.xml").toURI().toURL();
        //hiveConf.setHiveSiteLocation(url);
        //hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS,"thrift://l4283t.sss.com:9083,thrift://l4284t.sss.com:9083");
        HiveMetaStoreClient hiveMetaStoreClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveConf);
    }
```

The dependencies in the pom file:

```
</dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-metastore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Irrespective of whether I comment or uncomment the lines pertaining to the config and Kerberos, I receive the following exception which is explained on the [Hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool):

```
15:35:27.139 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler - MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7564)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7542)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:591)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:584)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:651)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:427)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6893)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:129)
at com.my.App.connectHiveMetastore(App.java:58)
at com.my.App.main(App.java:37)
15:35:27.141 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler - HMSHandler Fatal error: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7564)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7542)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:591)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:584)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:651)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:427)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:79)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6893)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:129)
at com.my.App.connectHiveMetastore(App.java:58)
at com.my.App.main(App.java:37)
Exception in thread "main" MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:83)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:92)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6893)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:164)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:129)
at com.my.App.connectHiveMetastore(App.java:58)
at com.my.App.main(App.java:37)
Caused by: MetaException(message:Version information not found in metastore. )
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.checkSchema(ObjectStore.java:7564)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.verifySchema(ObjectStore.java:7542)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.invoke(RawStoreProxy.java:101)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.verifySchema(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMSForConf(HiveMetaStore.java:591)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:584)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:651)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:427)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:148)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:107)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:79)
... 6 more
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have the following questions/concerns:

1. Is the way I am thinking about and connecting the HiveMetaStoreClient correct? If not, how do I retrieve the metadata information **provided by the methods of HiveMetaStoreClient**?
2. The code certainly isn't 'reaching' the cluster. Is the above exception pertaining to the dependency versions? If not, what can be the root cause?

Comment: Just drop a valid `hive-site.xml` file in a local directory, add that **directory** to the CLASSPATH, and just build a `new HiveConf(...)`. Then check that `hive.metastore.uris` has been initialized properly -- if the Hadoop clients don't find their config files in the CLASSPATH, they revert to hard-cded defaults -- which means an embedded metastore backed by a volatile Derby database.

Comment: Also, stop fooling around with POM files. Just get the Hive JARs present on your cluster -- plus a couple of Hadoop JARs because of Kerberos auth _(e.g. `hadoop-auth` and `commons-configuration`)_.

Comment: Speaking of Kerberos, either you have a Java-style Kerberos ticket available, or you willl need to initialize explicitly the static `UserGroupInformation` with principal & keytab... _(whereas JDBC can get principal / keytab directly from JAAS configuration)_

Comment: I will proceed with the approach that you have mentioned. Is it necessary to have a winutil even if I want to connect to a remote cluster? I have added the core-site,hdfs-site and hive-site to the classpath but I am getting 
Did not find winutils.exe: java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset. -see https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems

Comment: Ah, yet another shitty dependency thanks to the crappy Kerberos implementation (used by unit tests only but required always).

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855320/accessing-hdfs-on-cloudera-with-java-and-kerberos-keytab-from-windows/42927348

Comment: This approach seems to work, I still get the 'org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Invalid status -128' in spite of all the client config. but that's a separate issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the leads provided by @Samson(in comments), I gave the Maven approach and simply kept on copying the jars required from the cluster. Yes, this took a long time to get things sorted but I did make some progress.
Below is the class I am using, I still get SASL-related exceptions but at least the request is reaching the server.

```
private static void connectHiveMetastore() throws MetaException, MalformedURLException {

        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "E:\\Software\\Virtualization");

        /*Start : Commented or un-commented, immaterial ...*/
        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config","E:\\lib\\hdp\\loginconf.ini");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","E:\\lib\\hdp\\krb5.conf");
        /*End : Commented or un-commented, immaterial ...*/

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        /*Start : Commented or un-commented, immaterial ...*/
        configuration.addResource("E:\\lib\\hdp\\client_config\\HDFS_CLIENT\\core-site.xml");
        configuration.addResource("E:\\lib\\hdp\\client_config\\HDFS_CLIENT\\hdfs-site.xml");
        configuration.addResource("E:\\lib\\hdp\\client_config\\HIVE_CLIENT\\hive-site.xml");
        configuration.set("hive.server2.authentication","KERBEROS");
        configuration.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
        /*End : Commented or un-commented, immaterial ...*/

        HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf(configuration,Configuration.class);
        URL url = new File("E:\\lib\\hdp\\client_config\\HIVE_CLIENT\\hive-site.xml").toURI().toURL();
        HiveConf.setHiveSiteLocation(url);
        hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS,"thrift://l4283t.sss.se.com:9083,thrift://l4284t.sss.se.com:9083");
        /*Start : Commented or un-commented, immaterial ...*/
        hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.HIVE_SERVER2_AUTHENTICATION,"KERBEROS");
        /*End : Commented or un-commented, immaterial ...*/

        HiveMetaStoreClient hiveMetaStoreClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveConf);

        System.out.println("Metastore client : "+hiveMetaStoreClient);
        System.out.println("Is local metastore ? "+hiveMetaStoreClient.isLocalMetaStore());
        System.out.println(hiveMetaStoreClient.getAllDatabases());

        hiveMetaStoreClient.close();
    }
```